Understanding the Need for .map When Working with Optional and Interface Types in Spring Boot
I'm studying clean architecture building a simple Spring Boot application.
Some of my classes are:
public class EClient implements Serializable, EClientInterface {...}

public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<EClient, String> {...}

And finnaly, the reason of my question:
@Override
public Optional<EClientInterface> findClient(String cpf) {
    return repository.findById(cpf).map(eClient -> eClient);
}

Basically, I was forced to put a .map(eClient -> eClient), because my error message was:

Required -> Optional<EClientInterface>
Provided -> Optional<EClient>

To sum up, my questions are:

Why do I need the .map? Is it because Optinal only accpets the exact type and not implementations or subclasses?

Why does this map actually works? It looks redundant to me



It looks funny alright. If you want to make clearer to the reader why the map call is necessary, you may optionally write return repository.findById(cpf).map(eClient -> (EClientInterface) eClient);.

Generics are invariant.
Outside of the <>, Java is covariant: A subtype is just as good:
Integer i = 5;
Number n = i; // this is fine!

But inside the generics, Java is invariant - only the exact type is acceptable:
List<Integer> is = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> ns = is; // compiler error

That's because the type system would be broken if it wasn't like that. After all, if the above is legal, I can asplode the universe:
Double d = 5.5;
Number n = d; // obviously, legal.
ns.add(n); // this has to be legal too.
Integer i = is.get(0); // oh.. oh dear. kaboom

There's only one list here, and we added a double to it. Which means there is now a double in a list object that is referred to by a variable of type List<Integer>.
You need to opt into covariance, and return an Optional<? extends EClientInterface>. You read the question mark as 'do not know'. As in, you read that as: "An Optional that holds.. I do not know. All I know is, whatever the choice was that I don't know, it's either EClientInterface or some subtype of it".
The Java compiler will ensure that, whatever you do to such a thing, works for all possible choices one could make.
As an example, you can do this:
List<? extends Number> ns = someListOfIntegers;

But, as the compiler knows what it means and knows it must ensure that anything you do to ns is fine regardless of what ? extends Number> actually ends up being (it could be Integer, Double, Number, or some type some library you haven't even written yet is going to create; Number is not final nor is it sealed, after all). Hence, ns.add() cannot be called because you need to pass an expression of type T, and T here is 'do not know', so, no can do. Except the null literal because that's all types at once, but list.add(null) is rather pointless, of course.
If you for some bizarre reason MUST have Optional<EClientInterface> there, you're going to run into this problem a lot more, you can't always fix it so easily, and at least now you know why that map is 'necessary'. To work around the fact that generics just doesn't work the way you appear to think it does, and it doesn't work that way because the type system would be broken if it did.

You can also do List<Number> ns = Collections.unmodifiableList(someListOfIntegers); as it also prevents adding arbitrary Number instances. Unfortunately, there is no equivalent method for Optional.

@Holger, so the reason that calling map(), or unmodifiableList(), or any other method can solve the invariant generics problem is simply because the method creates a new instance, which guarantees there are no references to that instance as a different generic type?

@jaco0646 not exactly; all we're doing is 'satisfying the compiler'. The map operation allows the compiler to infer a conversion from EClient to EClientInterface. You could have also uglycasted it (cast to Object and then back to Optional<EClientInterface>. You'd get a load of warnings but the code would work fine and can't go wrong as far as I can tell because instances of Optional are immutable. The problem with 'add a double to a list of integers' cannot occur if the 'add' concept doesn't exist in any way. But javac doesn't know that.

"The map operation allows the compiler to infer a conversion..."  can you say a bit more about this? Why can't the compiler infer a conversion without the operation? What exactly are the requirements for "inference" to occur?

The compiler doesn't 'infer a conversion' because the compiler does not know the specifics of Optional. As far as it knows, it's just like List - you can't just treat a List<Integer> as a List<Number> because things go wrong when you do that. Optional has no add like methods. But javac does not know that / it might gain them in the future, so javac can't allow you to treat an Optional<Integer> as an Optional<Number>. That map operation literally produces a new optional.

@jaco0646 if Java supported declaration-site variance (like C# does) you could declare a type like Optional as read-only and assigning Optional<Integer> to Optional<Number> would be valid because a supplier of Integer is also a supplier of Number. But Java doesn’t have this. Java has use-site variance, so an operation like map can be implemented such that a Function returning a subtype of the target type’s type parameter is allowed. So you can pass an identity function returning the same Integer to map, to get an Optional<Number>.

The background for the underlying problem is explained here: What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?
In short, the error is not about anything in Optional, it is just how generics work - a Thing<A> is not a Thing<B>, even if an A "is a" B (in the sense of inheritance).
The argument of Optional.map() is a function converting the content of the Optional (of type EClient in your case) to a potentially different type, and the result is used to create a new Optional of the appropriate type. In your case the return type of the lambda you pass as a conversion function is derived to EClientInterface, therefore an explicit cast is not required here.
